# python matplotlib delaunay.delaunay warning error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a warning error that matplotlib.delaunay is deprecated.  I try to ignore this by a code like this:

```
def someFunction(N):

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  

# Initializes a random truss, with a few preset options
Somevariable = 23

for i in range(N-5):
  blablabla code

# Delaunay triangulation to get connections
varaibleX= delaunay.delaunay(Param 1, Param 2)  

return variableX
```

...

But I alwas get the warning...

Waht is the way ok doing it...

Best Regads,

Steph

Comment: What matploit version are you using?

Comment: 1.4.3

Thank you for the follow 
Steph

Comment: That is deprecated as you can read [here](https://github.com/ramezquitao/pyoptools/issues/33). From the perspective of software development, it is a bad idea to use deprecated components.